# A ready to use implementation of broker (mediator) based communication

Tags: .net, networking

I am not sure how to formulate the question correctly, so if there are better ideas - go ahead and suggest them.

The problem is simple. I have 2 peers A and B, both behind firewalls. I wish them to communicate with each other using a public broker or mediator, whichever name suits better.

The communication is asynchronous and goes something like this:

1. Both A and B periodically poll the broker asking whether there are messages for them.
2. When A wishes to communicate with B it sends a message to the broker, indicating that the message is for B.
3. When B polls the broker, the broker sees that there is indeed a message for it and responds accordingly.
4. B processes the messages and sends the response back to the broker, indicating that this is a response to the particular message from A.
5. At some point A polls the broker and receives back the response from B.

Now, before I rush in and implement this sort of communication myself, I am wondering whether there are ready to use packages that allow for this sort of communication out of the box.

Anyone?

Thanks.

**EDIT1**

I wish to emphasize that a peer may not have a message server installed on it. Meaning, simulating request-response with two one-way connections is not possible. I really need to be able to get a reply to peer's response, so it cannot be one-way communication.

**EDIT2**

One more constraint is that only HTTP(S) ports may be open for the communication, so the agents A and B may be in a situation where they communicate to the broker using HTTP(S) only.

Answer (score 1):

any esb wold do? For instance http://www.nservicebus.com/, or more lightweight: http://www.zeromq.org/

Comment: NServiceBus claim they are lightweight on their website. Do you have any first hand experience with any?

Comment: I've played with both. Nothing in production though. nservicebus is more lightweight than it have been. ZeroMQ is easier.

Comment: +1 for links, although I cannot see how NServiceBus helps me. It is one way messaging, whereas I need to be able to get replies to my requests. It cannot be simulated with messages, because I am not allowed to installed message servers on peers.

Comment: I have almost finished the ZGuide. Does not seem that ZMQ is going to be useful in my scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You can make this trivially (IMO) using any HTTPS stack.  The architecture of your broker depends on the volume and concurrency you need to handle.  Create a resource model such that your applications can PUT and GET messages, where the URI contains the destination node, and add a parameter for a reply address.  It should take you about 1 day to figure out a working resource model, 4 hours to code it up.  If you need volume, take a server like mongrel2 which has a zeromq backend.  Or node.js, which should do this admirably.

ZeroMQ is ideal for building concurrent apps but it's not a HTTP/S service, that's better handed by dedicated front-ends like mongrel2.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I was hoping that my need is not that bizarre and that there are ready off the shelf solutions. I guess there are none and I will have to implement them myself.

Answer (score 0):

Such broker exists as part of AppFabric in Azure platform. In AppFabric you can use [Service bus](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/appfabric/azure/middleware-services.aspx#ServiceBus) which allows such relayed communication. But you have to pay fees when using it.

Comment: Having the Azure platform is a bit of an overkill. Something lighter would be more appropriate.